# Find $a_n$ when $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}a_k$, $T_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{a_{k+1}}{S_k S_{k+1}}$, $S_{10}=25$, and $T_9=-\frac1{50}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Question:
>   $a_n$ is an arithmetic sequence, and
>   $$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}a_k$$
>   $$T_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{a_{k+1}}{S_k S_{k+1}}$$
>   If $S_{10}=25$, and $T_9=-\frac1{50}$, then identify $a_n$.

What I did so far:

If $a_n = a_1 +d(n-1)$, then
$$S_n = \frac{2a_1-d}4 - (-1)^n\cdot\frac{2a_1-d+2dn}4$$
$S_{10}=25$ gives $d=-5$.
$$S_n-S_{n-1}=(-1)^{n+1}a_n$$
$$a_n=(-1)^{n+1}(S_n-S_{n-1})$$
$$T_n=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\left(\frac1{S_k}-\frac1{S_{k+1}}\right)=-\frac1{S_1}+(-1)^{n+1}\frac1{S_{n+1}} + 2\sum_{k=2}^n (-1)^k\frac1{S_k}
$$
And then I am stuck.

Comment: It seems that the [possible values of $a$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-1%2F(50)%3D-1%2F(a)%2B1%2F(25)%2B2*(1%2F5-1%2F(a-5)%2B1%2F(10)-1%2F(a-10)%2B1%2F(15)-1%2F(a-15)%2B1%2F(20)-1%2F(a-20))) are ugly.

Comment: @mathlove Thanks. I got the same conclusion...